# Call java function using XQuery in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

Is it possible to call java function using XQuery in MarkLogic. ?

Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65953901/calling-java-method-from-xquery

Example -

```
declare namespace math="java:java.lang.Math";
math:sqrt(2)
```

Comment: At least for math functions you usually don't need other languages as `https://docs.marklogic.com/math:sqrt` https://docs.marklogic.com/math:sqrt exists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106085/call-java-from-marklogic-xquery-module suggests in-process calls to Java are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to directly call a Java function from MarkLogic XQuery. If the Java code is accessible through a web service, you can use `xdmp:http-get` and similar.

As noted by Martin, depending on what functionality you're trying to access, you might not need to use Java.